# Counting elements of list with Counter

Tags: python, nltk, counter

I'm new to python and programming and need your help.

I'm trying to count most common words in a text using `nltk.word_tokenize` and `Counter`. When I get the list of all elements of the text and I want to count all of them, `Counter` counts only letters.

This is the code:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

word_counter = Counter()

test3 = "hello, hello, how are you? It's me - Boris"
words = word_tokenize(test3)
print(words)
['hello', ',', 'hello', ',', 'how', 'are', 'you', '?', 'It', "'s", 'me', '-', 'Boris']

for word in words:
    word_counter.update(word)
print(word_counter)
```

The output:

```
Counter({'o': 5, 'e': 4, 'l': 4, 'h': 3, ',': 2, 'r': 2, 's': 2, 'w': 1, 'a': 1, 'y': 1, 'u': 1, '?': 1, 'I': 1, 't': 1, "'": 1, 'm': 1, '-': 1, 'B': 1, 'i': 1})
```

How could I solve that? I look through some topics, they solve it with `text.split()` but it is not so precise as `nltk`.

Thank you!

Comment: `Counter(words)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) as follows:

```
word_counter = Counter(words)
```

[`Counter.update`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update) takes an iterable and updates the counts for the elements the iterable produces. In your loop, that would be the letters of the word (remember strings are iterables).
If you were to use `update`, you could do:

```
word_counter = Counter()
# ...
words = word_tokenize(test3)
word_counter.update(words)
```

But there is no need to separate the initialization of the counter and the actual counting unless you want to repeat the second step for multiple lists of words.